# Difference between x[:1] and x[0]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working with tensorflow and numpy, and came across an issue where running a probability_model() on a single test example. My array, x_test is a 2d array.

```
probability_model(x_test[:1])
```

works properly, however

```
probability_model(x_test[0])
```

returns `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape Tensor("sequential_input:0", shape=(None, 28, 28), dtype=float32) for input (None, 28, 28), but it was re-called on a Tensor with incompatible shape (28, 28).`

I thought that x_test[0] and x_test[:1] would return the same 1D array, however it appears one results in a (None, 28, 28) dimensioned array, and the other results in a (28,28) array. So my question is not about tensorflow (I was just using it to show my error), do these expressions in fact result in different arrays, and if so what is the difference, because when analyzing their outputs they appear the same. Finally, is there an expression I can use to convert x_test[0] to the (None, 28, 28) size I need to call my function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple test shows that `arr[0]` returns the object in location in `0`, and `arr[:1]` returns the list cut out at index `1` (so just the first object).

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
print(a[0], a[:1])
```

Outputs:

```
1 [1]
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't have a lot of experience with numpy sorry. So then how can I get a[0] in the format of [1] and not 1.

Comment: Or is this the best way to get this behavior. For example if i want to return [2], what is the best way to do this

Comment: Simply `[a[2]]` should be enough. The more verbose way would of course be `a[1:2]`.

Comment: those are not the same, a[:1] = array([0]), but [a[0]] = [array(0)], or something like that

Comment: never mind a[[0]] provided the output i needed

Comment: Oh, my mistake -- you are using `numpy.array`, not the built-in `list`. In such case, indeed `np.array(a[0])` would work.